# How to put text on image with summernote

Tags: summernote

How to put text on image using summernote? or any way to achieve thing like that.
    I will appreciate any suggestion.

[image: Text on image],

Answer (score 0):

check summernote-image-attribute plugin  https://github.com/DiemenDesign/summernote-image-attributes